# Can I change a timer's interval without resetting it?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer that is supposed to generate a `Console.Beep` at the rate of my Heart Rate in beats/minute.  I am using the following simple formula to calculate the `Timer.Interval` in my **C#** timer:

```
    ServerVarValues = new ws ServerVarValues();
    this.timerHeartBeatSound = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);

    public class ServerVarValues
    {
        public int HR;
        public DateTime LastHRUpdate;
        public int SpO2;
        public DateTime LastO2Update;
        public double Temperature;
        public DateTime LastTempUpdate;
    }

 //... I plug in my heart rate to calculate my new timer interval...    
int tVal = (int)Math.Round((ws.HR / 60.0) * 1000,0);   
timerHeartBeatSound.Interval = tVal;

 // and with the new interval, the timer generates a Tick Event that runs this
   private void PlayHeartBeatSound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Beep();   
    }
```

I am reading my heart rate from a wearable. The problem is that every time that my HR changes, the timer is reset when I change the timer's interval. Thus, I hear hiccups often instead of a smooth changing heart rate sound.

Any ideas on how to avoid resetting the timer every time the heart rate changes?

Comment: There are several timer classes in .NET. No matter which one you're using, of course it always is possible to accommodate rate changes. Some timer classes are more amenable to this than others though. Depending on context, you may even find it preferable to use `Task.Delay()` in a loop instead of an actual timer, updating the delay value asynchronously as you receive new data. Provide a good [mcve] showing exactly what you're trying to do and reproducing the specific issue you're having trouble fixing.

Comment: Hi Peter - the code is really what you see. I set up a timer on visual studio, pass on the timer interval to it, and enable it. On the tick event, I call Console.Beep. What I don't want is everytime I change the time interval, because the heart rate changes, to reset the timer. I guess you are hinting at the fact the the visual studio timer is not the ideal one to use, and instead I should look at other classes.

Comment: _"the code is really what you see"_ -- really? you're able to compile the program you show above, without adding _anything_? Not a declaration of the `tVal` or `timerHeartBeatSound` variables, nor of `ws`, never mind a `class` and method declaration to contain the code? Please read the article [mcve] I referred you to earlier. See also [ask], including (and even especially) the articles linked at the bottom of that page. If you want help on Stack Overflow, you need to learn how to post a good question. You aren't doing that right now.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid being verbose, since that always get me into more trouble than being brief. I guess you're not married! I will post the full code later, according to Stack Overflow recommendations.

Comment: _"I was trying to avoid being verbose"_ -- that's a fine goal, and in fact required. **Do not _"post the full code"_.** But that doesn't mean you get to leave out critical information.

Comment: @LeoM - What do you mean by "I guess you're not married!"?

Comment: Hehe - I guess you're not married either if you don't understand the humor.

Comment: I totally understand that it is sometimes difficult to know how much to say. Sometimes I say too much and that distracts the discussion. The difference here is that they really don't like discussion in Stackoverflow, like what is happening here. Try posting a complete sample (as much as possible) that someone can put into VS and duplicate the problem then modify with a solution. Note that there is no such thing as a "visual studio timer".

Comment: You say "every time that my HR changes" but you don't say what the input is. That is critical. Are you notified of **every** heartbeat or are you notified periodically of what the heartbeat **rate** is?

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is by design.  When you change the Interval property, and it is not the same, then the Timer resets itself.  You cannot alter this behavior.

So what you must do is *not* update Interval.  Not until the next Tick happens.  Which is fine, the heart-beats happen quickly enough.  You'll need another variable:

```
public class ServerVarValues {
    public int NextInterval;
    // etc...
}
```

And initialize it when you start the timer or update the heart-rate value:

```
...
int tVal = (int)Math.Round((ws.HR / 60.0) * 1000,0); 
if (timerHeartBeatSound.Enabled) ws.NextInterval = tval;
else {
    ws.NextInterval = 0;
    timerHeartBeatSound.Interval = tval;
}
```

And in the Tick event handler you need to check if you have to make the new interval effective:

```
private void PlayHeartBeatSound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ws.NextInterval != 0) timerHeartBeatSound.Interval = ws.NextInterval;
    ws.NextInterval = 0;
    Console.Beep();   
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a perfect example of "thinking outside the box"! I just tried your idea and it works elegantly!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, except instead of "ASecond" use the number of milliseconds corresponding to the current heart rate. This will recalculate the number of milliseconds until the next beat, based on the current rate and do it for every beat. I hope it is smoother.

```
DateTime LastTime = DateTime.Now;

...

DateTime NextTime = LastTime + ASecond;
// Just in case we have gone past the next time (perhaps you put the system to sleep?)
if (DateTime.Now > NextTime)
    NextTime = DateTime.Now + ASecond;
TimeSpan Duration = NextTime - DateTime.Now;
LastTime = NextTime;
timer1.Interval = (int)Duration.TotalMilliseconds;
```